# Getting started with xamarin

Tags: android, visual-studio, sdk, xamarin.android

Here I created a "Blank App " on xamarin default templates that shows as "Welcome to xamarin forms " when it runs.
But I already created an virtual device using AVD by downloading necessary components on SDK
But when I hit run on my Virtual Device It cease and says:
`No resources fount that matches name :att 'colorAccent'`
and so on
It doesn't compile.
Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the MainActivity.cs is an out commented line: SetContentView(....), uncomment it and it should work

Comment: Thanks buddy. Can u explane  why there is a resource eror like 'no resources found to : attr 'windowColor' ''

Comment: Has that solves your problem? If yes, the MainAcitivy.cs is the code-behind from a view and so it is necessary to say the MainActivity.cs which view is coupled with the activity. If it solves your problem, can you vote up my answer with the up arrow?